# XSLT 1.0 loop through different child nodes of same parent

Tags: xslt

I have a xslt which needs to loop through three child nodes with different values and place them in a file.

So far it picks up only the first child and places these values in all three nodes in the resulting file. I tried many things but with no result, can someone please help me?

I searched this entire site many times over but to no avail.

This is a piece of the source which needs to be converted:

```
<followUpObjects>
<followUpObject length="4">
<followUpObjectNumber>1</followUpObjectNumber>
<followUpObjectTargetNumber>1</followUpObjectTargetNumber>
<followUpObjectName>Kostenplaats</followUpObjectName>
<followUpObjectValue desc="Kwaliteitsdienst">5260</followUpObjectValue>
</followUpObject>
<followUpObject length="13">
<followUpObjectNumber>2</followUpObjectNumber>
<followUpObjectTargetNumber>3</followUpObjectTargetNumber>
<followUpObjectName>kostensoort</followUpObjectName>
<followUpObjectValue desc="kostensoort1">kostensoort1</followUpObjectValue>
</followUpObject>
<followUpObject length="6">
<followUpObjectNumber>3</followUpObjectNumber>
<followUpObjectTargetNumber>2</followUpObjectTargetNumber>
<followUpObjectName>Project</followUpObjectName>
<followUpObjectValue desc="">2412</followUpObjectValue>
</followUpObject>
</followUpObjects>
```

I use this piece of xslt:

```
<CodingField>
<xsl:for-each
select="followUpObject[followUpObjectName='Kostenplaats']"></xsl:for-
each>
<Type>
<xsl:text>Costcenter</xsl:text>
</Type>
<Text>
<xsl:value-of
select="followUpObjects/followUpObject/followUpObjectValue"/>
</Text>
<Name>
<xsl:value-of
select="followUpObjects/followUpObject/followUpObjectValue/@desc"/>    
</Name>
<TextDetail>
<xsl:value-of
select="followUpObjects/followUpObject/followUpObjectValue"/>
</TextDetail>
<ShowAsSubLine>
<xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
</ShowAsSubLine>
</CodingField>
<CodingField>
<xsl:for-each
select="./followUpObject[followUpObjectName='kostensoort']"></xsl:for-
each>
<Type>
<xsl:text>Costunit</xsl:text>
</Type>
<Text>
<xsl:value-of
select="followUpObjects/followUpObject/followUpObjectValue"/>
</Text>
<Name>
<xsl:value-of
select="followUpObjects/followUpObject/followUpObjectValue/@desc"/>    
</Name>
<TextDetail>
<xsl:value-of
select="followUpObjects/followUpObject/followUpObjectValue"/>
</TextDetail>
<ShowAsSubLine>
<xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
</ShowAsSubLine>
</CodingField>
<CodingField>
<xsl:for-each
select="./followUpObject[followUpObjectName='Project']"></xsl:for-each>
<Type>
<xsl:text>Project</xsl:text>
</Type>
<Text>
<xsl:value-of
select="followUpObjects/followUpObject/followUpObjectValue"/>
</Text>
<Name>
<xsl:value-of
select="followUpObjects/followUpObject/followUpObjectValue/@desc"/>    
</Name>
<TextDetail>
<xsl:value-of
select="followUpObjects/followUpObject/followUpObjectValue"/>
</TextDetail>
<ShowAsSubLine>
<xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
</ShowAsSubLine>
</CodingField>
```

But I get this every time:

```
Type Costcenter
Text 5260
Name Kwaliteitsdienst
TextDetail 5260

Type Costunit
Text 5260
Name Kwaliteitsdienst
TextDetail 5260

Type Project
Text 5260
Name Kwaliteitsdienst
TextDetail 5260
```

As you can see, the first child is used everytime to fill in every other coding field except for the type (which I hard coded).

Comment: I have submitted an edit proposal. You had paragraphs formatted as code and code formatted as code formatting inside quotes (plus tags interpreted as HTML)

Answer (score 0):

You have three `xsl:for-each` blocks that are empty. For example...

```
<xsl:for-each select="followUpObject[followUpObjectName='Kostenplaats']"></xsl:for-each>
```

You should really put the code you want to execute for each item inside the `xsl:for-each`, not after it.

```
<CodingField>
  <xsl:for-each select="followUpObject[followUpObjectName='Kostenplaats']">
    <Type>
      <xsl:text>Costcenter</xsl:text>
    </Type>
    <Text>
      <xsl:value-of select="followUpObjectValue"/>
    </Text>
    <Name>
      <xsl:value-of select="followUpObjectValue/@desc"/>   
    </Name>
    <TextDetail>
      <xsl:value-of select="followUpObjectValue"/>
    </TextDetail>
    <ShowAsSubLine>
      <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
    </ShowAsSubLine>
  </xsl:for-each>
</CodingField>
```

Notice how the `xsl:value-of` statements do not need the full patch, but are relative to the `followUpObject` you are selecting.

Having said that, the `xsl:for-each` only selects one item, and you don't really want to repeat that code three times. So, instead, have `xsl:for-each` select all items....

Try this XSLT

```
 <xsl:for-each select="followUpObject">
   <CodingField>
    <Type>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="followUpObjectName = 'Kostenplaats'">Costcenter</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="followUpObjectName = 'kostensoort'">Costunit</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>Project</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </Type>
    <Text>
      <xsl:value-of select="followUpObjectValue"/>
    </Text>
    <Name>
      <xsl:value-of select="followUpObjectValue/@desc"/>   
    </Name>
    <TextDetail>
      <xsl:value-of select="followUpObjectValue"/>
    </TextDetail>
    <ShowAsSubLine>
      <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
    </ShowAsSubLine>
  </CodingField>
</xsl:for-each>
```

See this in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHUo/1

Comment: Wow, that's fast! I will try this at once! Thanks!

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried it out but I got a result without the values in the child nodes. The order seems okay but without values.

Comment: See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHUo/1 for an example of it in action.

Comment: Hi Tim, I think I am doing something wrong when putting your suggestion between the excisting code: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHUo/2

Comment: Change `<xsl:for-each select="followUpObject">` to `<xsl:for-each select="followUpObjects/followUpObject">`

Comment: Hi Tim, no change when I do that. I expect something is not right when I insert your piece of code because it meddles with the excisting code around it.